# Excel Interop - How to get the used range data with first unused columns?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have used the below code to retrieve data from excel. But it skips first empty columns becos of **Usedrange** property. How can I include that also?

```
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[2];
        Excel.Range excelCell = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        Object[,] values = (Object[,])excelCell.Cells.Value2;
```

Example

[image]

UsedRange returns B,C and D. But I need A also.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution, it may help someone.

```
 Excel.Range excelCell = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
 Excel.Range oRng = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1").SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);
        int lLastCol = oRng.Column;
        int colCount = excelCell.Columns.Count;
        int firstEmptyCols = lLastCol - colCount;
```